# forwarding all requests from one port to another nginix

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, system-administration, nginx-location

can i please know how to forward all the requests coming from port 80 to 443?
my code:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name myexample.com;

      location / {

              proxy_pass http://myexample.com:443/;

      }
}

server {

        listen 443;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html index.html index.php;
        server_name myexample.com;
}
```

but requests to http://myexample.com are not redirecting to https://myexample.com

Comment: Why do you proxy_pass, when you can/should redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: i thought proxy_pass will will do the forwarding .

Comment: Yes. It will. But the connection between the browser and website is still in HTTP (uncrypted). If your intention is to encrypt the connection, you should redirect HTTP to HTTPS, not proxy_pass.

Comment: i want to learn how to redirect http to https .. can u please explain me ?

Comment: Please see the answer

Comment: @robertwilliams You should edit your question, as what you are asking for is completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

```
server {
    listen 80;        
    server_name myexample.com;
    return  301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.html index.php;
    server_name myexample.com;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much..it's working.. can i please know what are the best books or resources to learn about nginx ?

Comment: Please find them on your favorite book stores (e.g. amazon, packt). If this answers your question, please accept as correct answer.

Comment: Search for "nginx".